# Voice keyboard delegates are not getting called in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

My application is working perfectly fine in ios7. But when I tried to run that on iOS 8 I am facing problem with keyboard when I am using voice keyboard to enter text into UITextView

`-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

method is not getting called. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: I have the same issues and i can't find any suggestion.